# How to disable save image and change the suffix to .htm when saving it?

Tags: html, css, permissions

How can I disable save image and change the suffix to .htm when saving it?

In fact, I need to change suffix during save, as is done on this site: [www.alexbuga.com](http://www.alexbuga.com)

Comment: Can you rephrase your question please?

Answer (score 0):

The website you linked to uses images as a background, so instead of

```
<img src="/path/to/image.png" width="200" height="200" alt="An image">
```

you would do this

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background: #fff url('/path/to/image.png') 0 0;"></div>
```

or similar. This doesn't exactly disable saving images but it's how the website you linked to works.